# Удаляется старое значение в файле

Tags: c++

В коде я расписал функции: File(), Modify() и Add_Sum_Avarage(). File() должна заполнять файл числами, Modify() делает некоторую модификацию(у меня умножает на -1, если число отрицательное), Add_Sum_Avarage() высчитывает сумму всей последовательности, находит среднее арифметическое(эти числа добавляются в конец контейнера), находит максимум и минимум и высчитывает среднее арифметическое между ними, потом добавляет это среднее к каждому элементу последовательности.

Проблема заключается в том, что когда в main пишу сначала

Код:

```
           File(50, 5);
           std::deque<double> D = inputfile_to_deque();
           Modify(D);
           Add_Sum_Avarage(D);
```

выводится Modify() и Add_Sum_Avarage().
Когда пишу
Код:

```
          File(50, 5);
          std::deque<double> D = inputfile_to_deque();
          Add_Sum_Avarage(D);
          Modify(D);
```

выводится только Modify(). В чем проблема? Должно выводится все File(), Modify() и Add_Sum_Avarage().

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cmath>

void File(int N, int count){
    
    std::ofstream out("input.txt");

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; ++i) {
        out << rand() % (2 * N + 1) - N << std::endl;
    }
    out << "File is done!" << std::endl;
}

std::vector<double> inputfile_to_vector() {
    std::vector<double> vec;

    std::fstream in("input.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);

    if (!in.is_open()) std::cout << "Cannot open file!\n";
    else {
        for (int x; in >> x; ) {
            vec.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    return vec;
}

std::deque<double> inputfile_to_deque() {
    std::deque<double> deq;

    std::fstream in("input.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);

    if (!in.is_open()) std::cout << "Cannot open file!\n";
    else {
        for (int x; in >> x; ) {
             deq.push_back(x);
        }
    }   
    return deq;
}

std::list<double> inputfile_to_list() {
    std::list<double> list;

    std::fstream in("input.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out);

    if (!in.is_open()) std::cout << "Cannot open file!\n";
    else {
        for (int x; in >> x; ) {
            list.push_back(x);
        }
    }
    return list;
}

template <class T>
T& Modify(T& X) {

    std::ofstream out("input.txt");
    
    typename T::iterator p;
    
    for (auto& i : X) {
        if (i < 0) {
            i *= -1;
        }
        out << i << " ";
    }
    return X;
}

template <class T>
 void Add_Sum_Avarage(T& conteiner) {
    std::ofstream out("input.txt");

    typename T::iterator pos;
    typename T::iterator pos1;
    typename T::iterator pos2;

    int MAX = 0;
    int MIN = 0;    
    int S = 0, N = 0;
    double SA = 0;
    for (const auto& i : conteiner) out << i << std::endl;
    for (pos = conteiner.begin(); pos != conteiner.end(); ++pos) {
        S += *pos;
        SA += *pos;
        N++;
    }   
    conteiner.push_back(S);
    conteiner.push_back(SA / N);
   
    out << "\nSum of container = " << S << std::endl;
    out << "Average of container = " << (SA / N) << std::endl;

    for (pos1 = conteiner.begin(); pos1 != conteiner.end(); ++pos1)
        if (MAX < *pos1) MAX = *pos1; out << "\nMAX = " << MAX << std::endl;

    for (pos2 = conteiner.begin(); pos2 != conteiner.end(); ++pos2)
        if (MIN > * pos2) MIN = *pos2; out << "MIN = " << MIN << std::endl;

    double Avarage = (MAX + MIN) / 2.0;
    out << "Avarage of max and min = " << Avarage << '\n' << std::endl;

    for (const auto& i : conteiner) out << (i + std::abs(Avarage)) << std::endl;    
}

int Random() { return rand() % (2 * 50 + 1) - 50; }

int main(){
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    File(50, 5);
    
    std::cout << "Making of container..." << std::endl; 
    std::vector<double> V = inputfile_to_vector();
    std::deque<double> D = inputfile_to_deque();
    std::list<double> L = inputfile_to_list();
    
    std::cout << "Changing of container..." << std::endl;   

    Modify(D);
    Add_Sum_Avarage(D);
}
```

Comment: Странно, что у вас выводится в одном варианте и то, и другое - потому что вы открываете файлы для перезаписи, так что в файле остается только введенное последним...

Comment: @Harry да, но как бы я мог исправить, чтобы выводилось все?

Comment: 1. Открывать файл для дозаписи в конец. 2. передавать методу объект потока - что логичнее: ну не должна дна функция заниматься и вычислениями, и открытием файла...

Comment: @ Harry Не подскажите, как я могу передать файл как аргумент в функции inputfile_...? я пишу ``` std::deque<int> inputfile_to_deque(std::ofstream& File)
``` но что тогда я должен написать в main, а именно в std::deque<double> D = inputfile_to_deque();

Comment: Вы должны сами открыть его (ну, типа, `ofstream out("filename");`, и передавать этот `out`.